# How to fire android back button from JavaScript when the button is triangle facing down? (hide keyboard)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, back-button

I am looking for a way to immediately hide the keyboard on input (type text) focus and the input to remain focused (in chromium, with JavaScript). Tried some things among which history.back() and history.go(-1) but this does what it says - page goes back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not up to you (the website) to hide the keyboard. Why you want to hide it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I want to use the input field as pure barcode scanner field and not confuse the users with the virtual keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works for Android.

```
function hideKeyboard() {
  //this set timeout needed for case when hideKeyborad
  //is called inside of 'onfocus' event handler
  setTimeout(function() {

    //creating temp field
    var field = document.createElement('input');
    field.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    //hiding temp field from peoples eyes
    //-webkit-user-modify is nessesary for Android 4.x
    field.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 0; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; left:0px;');
    document.body.appendChild(field);

    //adding onfocus event handler for out temp field
    field.onfocus = function(){
      //this timeout of 200ms is nessasary for Android 2.3.x
      setTimeout(function() {

        field.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.body.removeChild(field);
          document.body.focus();
        }, 14);

      }, 200);
    };
    //focusing it
    field.focus();

  }, 50);
}
```